# addChild() in Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

```
var c = new Cloud();
c.x = Math.random() * 350;
c.y = Math.random() * 700;
clouds.push(c);
stage.addChild(c);
```

This code is in my document class, I don't get any errors, tracing the x, y, or even c values show correct values. Alas the Cloud objects are not visible.

I have tried parent.addChild(c) and stage.addChild(c); nothing seems to show them.

(note my stage is 350 width and 700 height)

Comment: are you sure you're running in the DebugPlayer. Please also check what's in the constructor of your `Cloud` class and what is done in the class this code is in.

Comment: How do I ensure I am using "DebugPlayer">
The constructor for Cloud is empty.
This class is document class, it handles everything at the minute (moving one object around screen while spawning Cloud objects)

Comment: Right click on your Flash player, if you have the Debugger You'll see `Debugger` in the contextmenu. If the constructor is empty it's no surprise it's not showing since there is nothing to show yet. Please paste the content of the `Cloud` class. So we can double check what's wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is in the Cloud class, post it please so we can have a look

Comment: You say the code is in your document class and you have "tried parent.addChild(c) and stage.addChild(c)", but in the document class, I would think doing simply addChild(c) would be the normal case, so to speak.

Comment: The Cloud class is completely empty, has no constructor or functions or even variables.
I've tried creating a Cloud at 100,100 with a box around it, the box is visible fine but the Cloud is not.
addChild() [with no parent. or stage.] doesn't work either (it worked with the drawn rectangle but not this object).

Comment: 'package  {
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 public class Cloud extends MovieClip {
  public function Cloud() {
   // constructor code
  }
 }
}'

This is the Cloud class, as you can see, it does nothing and it's not supposed to yet, all I want is for them to appear on screen at the moment (will add movement later on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a sprite instance at (100, 100) and draw on it a black rectangle (width = 100, height = 100). If you see it then the problem with the cloud instance (the cloud white on the white background?), and you should check a drawing method of the Cloud class.

Comment: I've tried creating a Cloud at 100,100 with a box around it, the box is visible fine but the Cloud is not.

Comment: So the problem is not in the code shown. The addChild works fine. Look in your cloud class.

Comment: The Cloud class is completely empty so there isn't any code in there that could be wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that there is no code in the Cloud class, but you want to see an instance of the Cloud class? And why do you expect to see the cloud if you don't draw anything in it? And how do you expect to see it?

Comment: Well it was a graphic I drew then converted to a symbol?

Comment: Then there is the problem with symbol graphics. Maybe your symbol has an empty keyframe. Try to draw something in all frames of the symbol. Do you see it?

Comment: How strange, I went into the cloud object and scribbled over it with a red pen. Then it worked, I could see cloud and red pen.

I then deleted the scribble and it works, I can now see the cloud's original graphic. I have no idea how that helped but thank you :P